# Cecil fails to resolve assembly

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, mono.cecil

I have a Xamarin Forms app, consuming two in-house NuGet packages, with one depending on the other (lets call them Tools and BaseClasses, with BaseClasses having a dependency on Tools). However, when I update Tools from 1.0.63 to 1.0.64 in the app, I get an error when building the Android head project of the XF app.

```
Failed to resolve assembly: 'My.App.Tools, Version=1.0.63.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
   at Mono.Cecil.BaseAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference name, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Mono.Cecil.DefaultAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference name)
   at Mono.Cecil.MetadataResolver.Resolve(TypeReference type)
   at Mono.Cecil.TypeReference.Resolve()
   at Mono.Cecil.Mixin.CheckedResolve(TypeReference self)
   at Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder.GetConstantType(TypeReference constant_type, Object constant)
   at Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder.AddConstant(IConstantProvider owner, TypeReference type)
   at Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder.AddParameter(UInt16 sequence, ParameterDefinition parameter, ParamTable table)
   at Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder.AddParameters(MethodDefinition method)
   at Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder.AddMethod(MethodDefinition method)
   at Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder.AddMethods(TypeDefinition type)
   at Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder.AddType(TypeDefinition type)
   at Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder.AddTypes()
   at Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder.BuildTypes()
   at Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder.BuildModule()
   at Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder.BuildMetadata()
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleWriter.<>c.<BuildMetadata>b__2_0(MetadataBuilder builder, MetadataReader _)
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.Read[TItem,TRet](TItem item, Func`3 read)
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleWriter.BuildMetadata(ModuleDefinition module, MetadataBuilder metadata)
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleWriter.Write(ModuleDefinition module, Disposable`1 stream, WriterParameters parameters)
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleWriter.WriteModule(ModuleDefinition module, Disposable`1 stream, WriterParameters parameters)
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.Write(Stream stream, WriterParameters parameters)
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.Write(WriterParameters parameters)
   at Xamarin.AndroidX.Migration.CecilMigrator.Migrate(String source, String destination)
   at Xamarin.AndroidX.Migration.CecilMigrator.Migrate(IEnumerable`1 assemblies)
   at Xamarin.AndroidX.Migration.BuildTasks.CecilfyFiles.Execute()  My.App.Droid
```

The BaseClasses package has a dependency on Tools 1.0.63 or higher, so I'm quite confused as to why this problem suddenly pops up. So I checked the `project.assets.json` in the `obj` directory of the Android project folder, to verify the dependency tree showed anything weird. However, the dependency calculation seems to seems to be correct:

```
{
  "targets": {
    "MonoAndroid,Version=v10.0": {
      "My.App.BaseClasses/1.1.13": {
        ...
        "dependencies": {
          ...
          "My.App.Tools": "1.0.63",
        },
        ...
      },
      "My.App.Tools/1.0.64": {
        "type": "package",
        ...
      },
      ...
    }
  },
  "libraries": {
    "My.App.BaseClasses/1.1.13": {
      ...
    },
    "My.App.Tools/1.0.64": {
      ...
    },
    ... // Xamarin.Forms, Android support libs, etc, etc
  },
  "projectFileDependencyGroups": {
    "MonoAndroid,Version=v10.0": [
      ...
      "My.App.BaseClasses >= 1.1.13",
      "My.App.Tools >= 1.0.64",
      ...
    ]
  },
  "project": {
    ...
    "frameworks": {
      "monoandroid10.0": {
        "dependencies": {
          ...
          "My.App.BaseClasses": {
            "target": "Package",
            "version": "[1.1.13, )"
          },
          "My.App.Tools": {
            "target": "Package",
            "version": "[1.0.64, )"
          },
          ...
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem does not occur when I update Tools to 1.0.63 in my app, or when I update Tools to 1.0.64 in the BaseClasses package. But, having said that, I'm still in the dark as to why Cecil would want to resolve assembly Tools 1.0.63, when the app clearly is depending on at least version 1.0.64.

Some more logs from the android build in the Azure DevOps pipeline also shows that version 1.0.64 is being used and copied:

```
....
_CreatePackageWorkspace:
  Creating directory "obj\release\100\android\assets\".
_CopyConfigFiles:
  Creating "obj\release\100\stamp\_CopyConfigFiles.stamp" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
_ConvertPdbFiles:
Skipping target "_ConvertPdbFiles" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
_AndroidXCecilfyShrinkCopyFiles:
  Creating directory "obj\release\100\androidx\cecil".
  Creating directory "obj\release\100\androidx\cecil".
  Creating directory "obj\release\100\androidx\cecil".
  Creating directory "obj\release\100\androidx\cecil".
  ....
  Copying file from "C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\.nuget\packages\my.app.baseclasses\1.1.13\lib\monoandroid10.0\My.App.BaseClasses.dll" to "C:\agent\_work\25\s\app\My.App.Droid\obj\release\100\androidx\cecil\My.App.BaseClasses.dll".
  Copying file from "C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\.nuget\packages\my.app.tools\1.0.64\lib\netstandard2.0\My.App.Tools.dll" to "C:\agent\_work\25\s\app\My.App.Droid\obj\release\100\androidx\cecil\My.App.Tools.dll".
  
  ...
  
_AndroidXCecilfy:
  Migrated assembly to 'obj\release\100\androidx\cecil\My.App.Droid.dll'.
  ##[error]C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\.nuget\packages\xamarin.androidx.migration\1.0.8\buildTransitive\monoandroid90\Xamarin.AndroidX.Migration.targets(227,9): Error : Failed to resolve assembly: 'My.App.Tools, Version=1.0.63.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
  ...
```

Also tried using some different versions of the `Xamarin.AndroidX.Migration` package, but to no avail.

So my question is: What am I doing wrong, and how do I fix this, without being force to update the BaseClasses package to consume Tools 1.0.64?

Comment: Which version would not throw the error? Update Tools to 1.0.63 or 1.0.64? When you upgrade Tools to 1.0.63, does the BaseClasses have some features related to Tools 1.0.64?

Comment: The error is not throw if Tools=1.0.63, BaseClasses does not have some features related to Tools 1.0.64. I'm starting to suspect there's a bug in the AndroidX migration MSBuild task.

Comment: You could keep the old project and do the AndroidX migration on copied one.